# Do I need to verifiy a users email if they are sent a temporary password when an account is registered

Tags: email, passwords, registration, email-validation

I have a website where a user can login using MVC5 Identity. (Although this question is not specific to that technology)

For a user to register with this website we must have spoken to them over the phone and an account manager must go through a registration form which sets up an "unverified" account for the user.

Following this the user is sent an email verification link, along with a generated password to login. The registration you would normally fill out pre-login is done post-login.

So I was wondering if in this scenario I can simply treat the users first login as email verification becuase the only way they get their password is from the email.

Is there any way this could be exploited and open up any security holes/allow validation without owning the email?

Edit: 
Wanted to add the password is temporary (expires after a fixed period) and the user will be able to drop into a password reset form and a have a new one emailed if they don't do it in time. If the user has given us the wrong email I assume most will phone us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see this having any exploitation or holes and you are right to think this can be used as the email verification. Try it, and see how it works. Maybe after the temporary password is typed the user is prompted to type in a new password of their choosing.

Comment: Yup thats exactly the case. The user will change their password on the first page they see after login, and can go nowhere else until they have.